# Using django form many to many relationship model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am quite new to using Django, but basically I have two models: Student and Module

```
class Student(models.Model):
     student_id = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     birthday = models.DateField()

class Module(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     code = models.IntegerField()
     student = models.ManyToManyField(Student)
```

Now my question is, basically if I am using a Django form to add new students to the DB, how do I get the list of Modules I have in the DB.

I can add students to the module for adding a new module form, but not sure how to do it the other way

And say if I want to list all the modules a student is taking in a page, how do I access the modules those students are access to aswell?

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish the task. But as the more professional practice is to redesign the DB schema so that you don't any duplication of data in database as elaborated below.

```
class Student(models.Model):
     student_id = models.CharField(max_length=4, unique=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     birthday = models.DateField()

class Module(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     code = models.IntegerField()

class StudentsModule(models.Model):
     student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
     module = models.ForeignKey(Module)
```

**Explaination**

If you have list of users and want to add in the `Module` than you need to get list of `Students`(pk) from `Student` Model.

Create new `Module` and get the `pk` of `Module`.

You have list of `Students` and `Module`, Now You need to create records in `StudentsModule` Model. Create new row for each `Student` with `Module`.

**Example**

**Create Students**

```
  student_object1 = Student.objects.create(name="abc", birthday="2001-12-12")

  student_object2 = Student.objects.create(name="xyz", birthday="2005-12-12")
```

**Create Module**

```
  module_object = Module.objects.create(name="mno", code=123)
```

**Create StudentsModule**

```
  StudnetsModule.objects.create(student=student1, module=module_object)
  StudnetsModule.objects.create(student=student2, module=module_object)
```

Now you can access the list of `Modules` related with `Student` and the `Students` related to `Module`

Comment: Thank you - this make sense

Answer (score 0):

> how do I get the list of Modules I have in the DB.

```
Module.objects.all()
```

> how do I access the modules those students are access to aswell?

```
s = Student.objects.get(pk=1)
students_modules = s.module_set.all()
```